# How to generate this series?

Tags: php, hamming-distance, error-correction, hamming-code

What type of series it is and how to generate this by php program?

0 1 3 2 6 7 5 4 12 13 15 14 ...

Observation: The successive difference of the entity is 1

Example:

Difference of 0 and 1 is 1

Difference of 3 and 2 is 1

Difference of 6 and 7 is 1

Difference of 5 and 4 is 1

Difference of 12 and 13 is 1

Difference of 15 and 14 is 1

Please help ...

Comment: How are you getting from `0 1` to `3 2` and `3 2` to `6 7`? And _technically_ when working with sequences, the different between `0` and `1` is `1`. Whereas the difference between `5` and `4` is `-1`. You have provided too little information.

Comment: The diference between `2` and `6` is `4`. There are other values in the list that do not differ by `1`, such as `4` `12`. Provide more numbers of the series.

Comment: Once you figure out the algorithm, try coding it and we can review the code if you need to.  The algorithm part is not PHP related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a Decimal Equivalent of Gray code up to n. I have written a code to generate the [Gray code](https://oeis.org/A003188) for any Number, Use this to generate a series. I have used Javascript, but you can choose any language you want.

```js
   Number.toGrayCode = function(n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            throw new RangeError("cannot convert negative numbers to gray code");
        }
        return n ^ (n >>> 1);
    };
    
   for( var i=0;i<=10;i++)
    console.log(Number.toGrayCode(i));
```

Comment: Awesome! You are my hero. Great job Tushar. Thanks